# how to change non app settings in web config of azure web app

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a web app deployed on azure using Armtemplate & powershell.

Web app configured with following settings in web config

```
    <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="urn: test1" />
      </audienceUris>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
      <issuerNameRegistry>
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="sfsfssfsfsfsdf" name="test" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <add type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler"/>
        <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler" />
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>
  <system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://testurl" realm="urn: test" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="sample" />
    </federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
```

I need to change some values based on clients configurations such as urn:,thumbprint and federation redirect url.
Currently, I am editing web config manually by using advance tools(Kudu debug console) in portal.

It is not an easy process for any third person who is unaware of it so
I would like to set/change these value from powershell or armtemplate or portal(rather using advanced tools) as the same way we set/change values of app settings.

Is there any other way or best way to change this tags?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only modify the limited set of settings through the Portal and otherwise. Which means your options are:

1. Edit the Web.Release.config (or similar) and re-publish
2. Do the whole configuration for whatever you are trying to do programmatically (I'm not sure if it can be done in this case)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not sure if the application restarts or the worst case it redeployed and my changes in web config overwritten with the old one that is the reason I am looking to automate this thing. Is there any PowerShell command which replaces the values while deploying?